# Typscript tooling for measuring “any” usage? Akin to code-coverage scores?

Tags: angular, typescript

Our teams are trying to drive down their abuse of ‘any’ and lean more into the typesystem.

Any tsc tooling to measure the use of ‘any’ in a project? And use that to block builds so that our abuse of ‘any’ doesn’t get worse.

Comment: Open your editor and do a regex search for `any`.

Comment: It's not `tsc`, but would you accept an answer of [eslint-stats](https://github.com/ganimomer/eslint-stats) mixed with [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) and rules like [typedef](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/typedef/) as [advised](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/3979)? Then you could on a per-file basis see how close you are to full typing, with some adjustment over where and how you want to enforce rules.